# AutoIt for web browser

Tags: automation, autoit, rpa, hwnd

I want to automate using AutoIt for any browser. My scenario is like visiting the website  ebay.
Then fill in the text to search and click on  **search** button. Then select the categories "Cell Phones & Accessories".
My code below is just able to open the browser. I know they are using something like `handle or hWnd` to work it out.

```
$url = "https://www.ebay.com.my/"

ShellExecute($url,"","","open")

Sleep(1000)

Send("apple")
```

Comment: Once you visited the website,what text you want to search in ebay website?

Comment: `$url = "https://www.ebay.com.my/sch/i.html?_nkw=pink%20cover&_sacat=15032`, where `15032` is the category (doublecheck, I'm on another language) and `pink%20cover` is your search string (spaces to be replaced by `%20`)